# Concatenate in For-Next Loop

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that houses 37 columns across, and 13,580 down. My goal is to take take the same information and export it as is into a notepad. From the research that i've done. It isnt possible because the character limit is 240, and my spreadsheet in a maximum of 256.

What makes this so much harder than it needs to be, is that i cant just grab "A1:AK1" and paste it. I have requirements that i want each column, and string to posses. Such as:

- I want my exported text to be ALL caps.(its too much trouble to copy and paste between Word to Excel to Word, to get the results. Large texts of data can cause lag in that
  process as well).
- There's a Max Character limit for each Column (They dont all contain the same limit, each one may be different than the last)
- I dont desire a delimiter, but one has to be automatically inserted, and varies in size, depending on the character limit (The columns have to fall in line in the notepad, so that they can be imported correctly.)
- If at all possible, this is something extra, but if the `Trim()` function could be included, in case there excess spaces involved in some of the values
- Oh, and i almost forgot, some of the values that are aligned in the notepad, are left align, and some are right align. (Ex. Below)

img : h_ttp://i.stack.imgur.com/pCvDW.png
(there's a void of space and some of the values fall on the right side, and other start from the left)

**What i've attempted**

```
    'from rows 1 to end
    'for every column in row#
    'right align=space(30 - characterlength(column[row#])) & column[row#]  &
    'left align=column[row#] & space(30 - characterlength(column[row#])) &

    txt =  txt & UCase(_
    rnSelect.Range("B" & lgl).Value & _
    rngSelect.Range("C" & lgl) & Space(14 - Len(rngSelect.Range("C" & lgl))) & _
    rngSelect.Range("D" & lgl) & Space(8 - Len(rngSelect.Range("D" & lgl))) & _
    Left(Trim(rngSelect.Range("E" & lgl)), 12) & Space(12 - Len(rngSelect.Range("E" & lgl))) & _
    Left(Trim(rngSelect.Range("F" & lgl)), 30) & Space(30 - Len(rngSelect.Range("F" & lgl))) & _
    Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("G" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("G" & lgl)  & Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("H" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("H" & lgl)  & 
    Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("I" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("I" & lgl)  & Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("J" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("J" & lgl)  & _
    Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("K" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("K" & lgl)  & Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("L" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("L" & lgl)  & _
    Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("M" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("M" & lgl)  & Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("N" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("N" & lgl)  & _
    Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("O" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("O" & lgl)  & Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("P" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("P" & lgl)  & _
    Space(8 - rngSelect.Range("Q" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("Q" & lgl)  & Space(4 - rngSelect.Range("R" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("R" & lgl)  & _
    Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("S" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("S" & lgl)  & Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("T" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("T" & lgl)  & _
    Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("U" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("U" & lgl)  & Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("V" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("V" & lgl)  & _
    Space(1 - rngSelect.Range("W" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("W" & lgl)  & Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("X" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("X" & lgl)  & _
    Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("Y" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("Y" & lgl)  & Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("Z" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("Z" & lgl)  & _
    Space(2 - rngSelect.Range("AA" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AA" & lgl)  Space(6 - rngSelect.Range("AB" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AB" & lgl)  & _
    Space(2 - rngSelect.Range("AC" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AC" & lgl)  Space(2 - rngSelect.Range("AD" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AD" & lgl)  & _
    Space(1 - rngSelect.Range("AE" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AE" & lgl)  Space(1 - rngSelect.Range("AF" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AF" & lgl)  & _
    Space(1 - rngSelect.Range("AG" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AG" & lgl)  Space(1 - rngSelect.Range("AH" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AH" & lgl)  & _
    Space(2 - rngSelect.Range("AI" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AI" & lgl)  Space(5 - rngSelect.Range("AJ" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AJ" & lgl)  & _
    Space(5 - rngSelect.Range("AK" & lgl).Count) & rngSelect.Range("AK" & lgl)  Space(3) & vbCrLf )

    'add 3 spaces and a LineFeed
    'next row
```

In the end, all i get is an error, cause everything is in one line, and i'm not exactly too sure how to break it down.

*P.S. Every other part of the code, besides the one i pasted is/was generic, i found them throughout my research on countless sources. It simply stated the export function/script.*

Is it possible to Concatenate such a large macro? If not, is there a loop that i can use?
All i want is for it copy and paste as is into notepad, but spaced out accordingly (Cant rely on column width, cause i'm not too sure how many characters can fit within a certain parameters).

Please and thank you.

---

**EDIT**
Okay, I'd like to thank @codejockey for the help that he's given me so far. I'm getting results, just not the ones that i like. The script is working, and it moves very quickly (surprisingly).

Here is the code that i'm using:

```
Public Function ProcessCell(inputString As String, colNum As Integer) As String
Dim tempString As String
Select Case colNum

Case 1    'Column "A"
    tempString = UCase("TEST")
Case 2, 3    'Column "B" & "C"
    tempString = tempString & Space(14 - Len(inputString))
Case 4    'Column "D"
    tempString = tempString & Space(8 - Len(inputString))
Case 5    'Column "E"
    tempString = tempString & UCase(Trim(Left(inputString, 12))) & Space(12 - Len(Trim(inputString)))
Case 6    'Column "F"
    tempString = tempString & UCase(Trim(Left(inputString, 30))) & Space(30 - Len(Trim(inputString)))
'
'    Keep Going...
'
Case 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(8 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 16, 17    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(6 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 18    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(4 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 19, 20, 21, 22    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(6 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 23    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(1 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 24, 25, 26    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(6 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 27    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(2 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 28    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(6 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 29, 30    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(2 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 31, 32, 33, 34    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(1 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 35    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & Space(2 - Len(inputString)) & inputString
Case 36, 37    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    tempString = tempString & inputString & Space(5 - Len(inputString))
'
End Select

tempString = tempString & Space(3) & vbCrLf
ProcessCell = tempString

End Function
```

But the results that i'm getting are https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaGeI.png where its going down, instead of more across... like the first link https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCvDW.png

The script i'm using that's not included in the function looks like this:

```
Dim rngSelect As Variant
Set rngSelect = Range("A2:AI3")
Dim lgl As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lgl = 1 To lastRow

    For i = 1 To 37
        oneLine = oneLine & ProcessCell(rngSelect.Cells(lgl, i), i)
    Next i
oFile.Write oneLine
oneLine = vbNullString
Next

Set rngSelect = Nothing

oFile.Close
```

What am i doing wrong, i dont know how to fix it, or why it looks the way it does... it seems there are extra LineFeeds in the code, but i only inserted linefeed once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** break this "line" of code down into simpler steps!

Write a function that takes a string and processes it the way you want.

```
Public Function ProcessCell(inputString as String, colNum as Integer) As String
    Dim tempString as String
    Select Case colNum

    Case 2    'Column "B"
        tempString = inputString
    Case 3    'Column "C"
       tempString = inputString & Space(14 - Len(inputString))
    '
    '    Keep Going...
    '
    Case 6, 7, 8, 9    'Example for multiple cases handled the same way
    '
    '
    End Select

    ProcessCell = tempString

End Function
```

Now, you can just loop through all the columns:

```
For i = 1 To 37
    oneLine = oneLine & ProcessCell(rngSelect.Cells(lgl, i), i)
Next i
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: This seems simple enough to work, thank you for your quick reply. I'm attempting to implement the code now, but i have a concern that is troubling me.. Right now, i'm still classed as a beginner to coding, how do i get `Case 2, 3 'Column "B" & "C" tempString = inputString & Space(14 - Len(inputString))` to manipulate with dynamic variables such as the current column/row?

Comment: In my example, i use the `Range.Cells` property, which allows you to pass an integer for the row / column you want to refer to.  `myRange.Cells(1, 3)` will return the cell in the first row, third column of `myRange`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for inputs, and responses to my concerns and questions. I believe i correctly altered the function to work with my spreadsheet without causing any issues. Two things tho... I'm a little iffy when it comes to the UDF. did i do this correctly? `tempString = inputString & Range(colNum & lgl)` or was i supposed to use `tempString = inputString & Range(colNum & i)` instead?

Comment: i'm getting an object defined error on `oneLine = oneLine & ProcessCell(rngSelect.Cells(lgl, i), i)` I've tried defining `oneLine` as String, Variant, and Long... nothing is working, am i missing something. Its the only piece of the code not working right now. (the main core of the code)

Comment: To your first question, the way I have written it, `ProcessCell` has no concept of cell, it merely adds spaces according to your rules and returns that string.

Comment: To your second question: what is the value of `i` and `lgl` when you are getting this error?  You will get Object Defined Error if you try to access the "0th" column or row OR any negative row.

Comment: shouldnt ProcessCell have a concept of cells/ranges for what i need it to perform? I realized you can hover the mouse over a variable and it will tell you the value

Comment: Omg, awesome, works perfectly! i fixed the kinks and works just like it's supposed to, and a LOT quicker than i expected as well. I assumed it would go row by row. But once i execute the macro, there's already a saved file waiting.